# Android application failed to install in ICS

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an application compiled with Android 2.2 and API level 8. It works perfectly on gingerbread devices. Now when I tried to install the same apk file on ICS 4.0.3 device for testing, I got an error "Unfortunately, package installer has stopped". 
I am totally new in android development and any help is highly appreciated.

Following is my Manifest.xml file:-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.quickshop"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<supports-screens
android:largeScreens="true"
/>

<application
android:icon="@drawable/quicklogo"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
android:name=".SplashScreen"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
android:name=".QuickShop"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
<activity
android:name=".Download"
android:label="@string/app_name" >


</activity>
<activity
android:name=".QuickShopCameraActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name">


</activity>
<activity
android:name=".QuickShopPreviewActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
<activity
android:name=".QuickShopActionActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name">

</activity>
<activity
android:name=".QuickShopProductDetails"
android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
<activity
android:name=".TestActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your application to run on ics, you have to include this attribute in your manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" 
      android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

This way your application will be compatible from cupcake to ice cream sandwich.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

add this in the manifest

Comment: The device that u may be using may not be allowing it.Just check whether this work for U.
                                                                   Go to Settings > Applications and you'll see a checkbox that by default is unchecked- it's named 'Unknown sources'.It's a security setting so that users can only install apps from the Play Store.

Comment: Nope its checked. unknown sources are allowed

Comment: Manually put the apk. in the device and install and also try installing another application directly through Run Configuration. which will let u knw whether there is any problem with device or ur application